# Triple integral in cylindrical coordinates question

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Can someone explain the answer given split the integral into a cylinder and volume below a sphere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is a graph of the situation:  we have a hemisphere (above the $ \ xy-$ plane) of radius 2, centered on the origin, intersected by a plane parallel to the $ \ xy-$ plane and 1 unit "above" it.  The "level curve" on the plane $ \ z = 1 \ $ is the circle $ \ x^2 + y^2 + 1^2 = 4 \ \Rightarrow \ x^2 + y^2 = 3 \ . $  So that circle has a radius of √3 .

[image]

If we now imagine "looking upward" from the $ \ xy-$ plane, we see that the volume that is described by the triple integral we are asked to set up has a "wall" formed by the spherical surface and a flat circular "ceiling".  So we can handle the calculation of the volume by using two integrals, one of which gives the volume of a cylinder of radius √3 and a height of 1 [the first integral shown -- though we really can get *this* volume without calculus], and the other gives the volume from the spherical surface down to $ \ z = 0 \ $ in a ring (annulus) from $ \ r = \sqrt{3} \ $ to $ \ r = 2 \ $ [the second integral shown].

Comment: I just saw this once more and it makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!